# Search for list of keywords in python

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, keyword

I've been able to search for keywords in strings before, but I'm running into a problem with using a list to do so. I keep getting this error.

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bool
```

I've tried every solution I could think of, but this is where I'm at right now:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

keywords = ['diy','decorate', 'craft', 'home decor', 'food']

def get_tags(blog_soup):
    tags_html = blog_soup.find('div', attrs = {'style': 'margin-left: 60px; margin-bottom: 15px;'})
    tags = [tag.string for tag in tags_html.findAll('a')]
    string_tags = str(' '.join(tags))
    if any(keywords) in string_tags:
        print url

url = 'http://technorati.com/blogs/blog.mjtrim.com'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

get_tags(soup)
```

Comment: You want `if any(i in string_tags for i in keywords)` or some such thing instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a minimal change to get this working, you can change `any(keywords) in string_tags` to the following:

```
any(keyword in string_tags for keyword in keywords)
```

Or an alternative using sets:

```
keywords = set(['diy','decorate', 'craft', 'home decor', 'food'])

def get_tags(blog_soup):
    tags_html = blog_soup.find('div', attrs = {'style': 'margin-left: 60px; margin-bottom: 15px;'})
    tags = [tag.string for tag in tags_html.findAll('a')]
    if keywords.intersection(tags):
        print url
```