# What is the code equivalent to grep -B in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I print n lines before a matched string from a file using python?

> **man grep**
>
> > -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
> >
> > Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines. Places a
> >     line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of
> >     matches. With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and
> >     a warning is given.

I have code for grep -A:

```
def grepA(word,file,num=0):
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if word in line:
                print(line + ''.join(islice(file, num)))
                print('---')
```

Comment: @vishes_shell: interesting link. How does that solution  work for `-A` and `-B`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll just have to keep a buffer (a list) of the N last lines, then print them when you encounter a match.

```
context_lines = []
for line in f:
    context_lines.append(line)
    if len(context_lines) > 5:  # Too many lines?
        context_lines.pop(0)  # Pop the first one off.
    if word in line:
        # context_lines already includes the `line` we're looking at
        for ctx_line in context_lines:  
             print(ctx_line)
```

Comment: I would have used a `deque` with a history of 5 (much more efficient)

Comment: Sure, that'll work too. :)

Comment: it`s work,but the output in the console adds spaces that are not in the source file

Comment: @VladimirSmith If `line`s already contain newlines, then you'll want to `print(ctx_line, end='')`, yeah :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to cache the lines:

```
def grepb(word,file, num=0):
    if num == 0:
        print(re.findall(re.compile(word), line)[0])  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659142
    else:
        cache = collections.deque([], num)
        with open(file) as f:
            for line in f:
                cache.append(line)
                if word in line:
                    print('\n'.join(cache))
                    print('---')
```

Comment: the best answer so far